# Titanium: Unable to install app on physical device

Tags: ipad, ios5, segmentation-fault, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have a Titanium mobile app that is working fine on iOS simulator, But when I try to install same application on physical device, it stops installation progress in middle. I could see some error trace in organizer console. Here is the error trace

```
Jun 15 01:53:41 unknown misagent[147] <Error>: profile not valid: 0xe8008011
Jun 15 01:53:41 unknown lockdownd[21] <Error>: 001ff000 copy_phonenumber: CTSettingCopyMyPhoneNumber() returned NULL
Jun 15 01:53:41 unknown lockdownd[21] <Error>: 001ff000 copy_iccid: invalid ICCID from CT/no ICCID available
Jun 15 01:53:41 unknown lockdownd[21] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copyMobileEquipmentIdentifier: No MEID in CT mobile equipment info dictionary - <CFBasicHash 0xd611fe0 [0x3f209630]>{type = mutable dict, count = 3,
entries =>
    2 : <CFString 0xd611f90 [0x3f209630]>{contents = "kCTMobileEquipmentInfoCurrentMobileId"} = <CFString 0xd611fc0 [0x3f209630]>{contents = "012804009362089"}
    4 : <CFString 0xd612010 [0x3f209630]>{contents = "kCTMobileEquipmentInfoICCID"} = <CFString 0x3f1fd9d0 [0x3f209630]>{contents = ""}
    11 : <CFString 0xd612780 [0x3f209630]>{contents = "kCTMobileEquipmentInfoIMEI"} = <CFString 0xd611fc0 [0x3f209630]>{contents = "012804009362089"}
}
Jun 15 01:53:41 unknown lockdownd[21] <Error>: 001ff000 copy_meid: MobileGestalt failed to provide an MEID but returned no error (?)
Jun 15 01:53:45 unknown ReportCrash[156] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process installd[135]
Jun 15 01:53:45 unknown com.apple.itunesstored[133] <Notice>: receive_message: failure running async function: 1
Jun 15 01:53:45 unknown com.apple.itunesstored[133] <Notice>: call_and_response: Could not receive response from proxy
Jun 15 01:53:45 unknown com.apple.itunesstored[133] <Notice>: MobileInstallationInstall: failed with -1
Jun 15 01:53:45 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (com.apple.mobile.installd) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
Jun 15 01:53:45 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (com.apple.mobile.installd) Throttling respawn: Will start in 2 seconds
Jun 15 01:53:45 unknown ReportCrash[156] <Error>: Saved crashreport to     /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/installd_2012-06-15-015345_EpocDev-iPad01.plist using     uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
```

Certificates and profiles are fine as XCode build succeeds always. I dont know what is happening. This is my 4th titanium app. I posted it on titanium forum as well but have not got any reply since long. I am totally frustrated now. Any help is highly appreciated.

Here is the development environment:

**Application type**: mobile

**Titanium SDK**: 1.8.3 (05/29/12 16:47 427f3c5)

**Platform & version**: iOS 5.0

**Device**: physical iPad device (with iOS 5.0.1 (9A405))

**Host Operating System**: OSX 10.6.8

**Titanium Studio**: 2.0.1

**XCode**: 4.2

Please Help :(

Comment: Is there a profile installed on the phone? And is the phone ID in the certificate?

Answer (score 1):

I had some unexplainable troubles with a combination of that Xcode version and that SDK as well, if I remember correctly. What you may want to do, is one of these scenarios:

(1) use an older SDK version, e.g. 1.7.x

(2) upgrade to XCode 4.3 and SDK 2.x - but note that this brings some changes!! Xcode is in a different folder (/Applications, you now download it using the App Store for Mac), so there is a need for some reconfiguration. Cannot remember what I had to to, but at least the issues can be solved. I am now running Xcode 4.3 with Ti SDK 2.0.2GA and had no compilation issues 2 days ago.

Does this work for you?

Comment: Hi @Pieter. I appreciate your reply. I tried downgrading it to sdk 1.7.2 and tried to install it. But it did not work

Comment: I also creating a new sample app using sdk 1.7.2 and tried installing it but problem persists.

Comment: And if you upgrade to XCode 4.3 and SDK 2.x ?